# No validator could be found for type: java.lang.String

Tags: spring, validation

Trying to validate the data entered in my registration form.

Error Message: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.String.

Model Class:

```
@Configuration
public class Student {

    private int studentId;

    @NotNull(message = "First name should not be empty")
    @Size(min=03, max=20, message = "Minimum 3 to  Maximum 20 characters are allowed")
    @Pattern(regexp="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "Last name should not be empty")
    @Size(min=03, max=20, message = "Minimum 3 to  Maximum 20 characters are allowed")
    @Pattern(regexp="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull(message = "Display name should not be empty")
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", message = "Please enter a valid display name")
    @Size(min=05, max=15, message="Minimum 3 to Maximum 15 characters are allowed")
    private String displayName;

    @NotNull(message = "Date of birth should not be empty")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd/")
    @Past (message="Only the past date is valid")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    @NotNull(message = "Email should not be empty")
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Password should not be empty")
    @Pattern.List({
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[0-9])",    message = "Password must contain one digit."),
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[a-z])",    message = "Password must contain one lowercase letter."),
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=.*[a-z])",    message = "Password must contain one lowercase letter."),
        @Pattern(regexp = "(?=\\S+$)",  message = "Password must contain no whitespace.")
    })
    private String password;

    @NotNull(message="Contact shouldnot be empty")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message="Contact should only contain numbers")
    @Size(min=10, max=10)
    private String contact;

    @NotNull(message="Select atleast one skill from the list")
    private List<String> studentSkills;

    // Getter and Setter for studentId
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for firstName
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for lastName
    public String getLastName() {   
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for displayName
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }
    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for DateOfBirth
    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for email
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for password
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for contact
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for studentSkills
    public List<String> getStudentSkills() {
        return studentSkills;
    }
    public void setStudentSkills(List<String> studentSkills) {
        this.studentSkills = studentSkills;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registration", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRegForm() {
    ModelAndView mv =   new ModelAndView("registration","student",new Student());
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/submitregistrationform", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitRegForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView registrationView = new ModelAndView("registration");
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return registrationView;
    } else {
        st.insertOrUpdate(student);
        ModelAndView mv =   new ModelAndView("login");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to sort the exception ?
I tried length for String just to see if it works. But it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validations given for date are incorrect. As the date is in String format and the annotation checks for DATE datatype it is throwing a exception.
Changed the data type of date from String to DATE and it started working.